# Required package 'bdertl'/'vcljpg' not found upgrading from Delphi2007 to DelphiXE7

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I'm upgrading an old project from *Delphi 2007* to *Delphi XE7*.

On compiling, I get the following error:

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] MyProject.dpk: E2202 Required package 'bdertl' not
>   found

If I remove it from the project file's `requires` clause then I get the following error:

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] MyProject.dpk: E2202 Required package 'vcljpg' not
>   found

If I also remove this one then the project compiles without errors.

Should they be simply removed or should they be replaced with something else?

Comment: `vcljpg` is replaced by `vclimg` since Delphi2009.

Comment: `bdertl` is a runtime package for BDE database engine that no longer ships with newer Delphi versions so you will either have to add it to your Delphi manually or switch all of your database components to some other database. I belive migrating from BDE to FireDac is the easiest .

Comment: @SilverWarior:  Iirc, the BDE stuff still ships with Delphi but isn't installed by default.

Comment: @LURD: thanks! if my project after removing them compiles without errors, does it mean that it don't need them anymore?

Comment: @SilverWarior: thanks! if my project after removing them compiles without errors, does it mean that it don't need them anymore?

Comment: Simply removing those packagnes and getting your application to compile doesn't necessarily means that you don't need them. Depending on how those packages are implemented in your project removing them might remove some functionality of your application but not cause any compilation errors. For instance `vcljpg` registers needed classes to work with JPEG images. Removing this unit Will remove the ability of your application to properly open and show JPEG images.

Comment: @Fabrizio, whether the units/packages are needed, would be depending on the application. A compilation success is by no means a proof of a working application.

Comment: Just a side note to everybody in case you didn't notice: This seems to be a package, not an application. It's unlikely to compile if it needs the bde. I think the same also applies to vcljpg.

Comment: @dummzeuch: Yes, it is a package. In case of a package, if it compile without errors I can remove the requires without worrying?

Comment: @LURD Are you sure that `vcljpg` is replaced by `vclimg`? I can find `vclimg` also on Delphi2007

Comment: It might as well be D2007. I only concluded D2009 from [this](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.rtl/201010/1010153980.html) answer by Peter Below, where he assumed it was introduced in the first unicode Delphi version.

Comment: @LURD: Thanks for sharing the link. I mean that in _D2007_ there are both `vcljpg` and `vclimg` (I suppose that the content of `vcljpg` could have been moved to `vclimg` with _D2009_ but I didn't found any official information about that)

Comment: From [D2009, Whats new](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/2010/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_2009#VCL_and_RTL): *VCLJPG to VCLIMG: The vcljpg package was removed and its contents are now in vclimg. Update projects using vcljpg to use the vclimg package instead.*

Comment: @LURD Great! Thank you

Comment: @LURD: You can post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `vcljpg` package has been removed and replaced with `vclimg` since Delphi 2009.

See [D2009, Whats new](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/2010/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_2009#VCL_and_RTL):

> VCLJPG to VCLIMG: The vcljpg package was removed and its contents are now in vclimg. Update projects using vcljpg to use the vclimg package instead.